# Generate a single ouput in AWK script

Tags: linux, awk

I have this code in a test.awk file:

```
{FS=","} {gsub(/\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}/,"");}1

{FS=","} {gsub(/:[0-9][0-9]/,"");}1
```

The code makes transformations in a dataset from a dataset.csv file.
I want that using the following command at the shell, returns me
a newdataset.csv with all the modifications:

```
gawk -f test.awk dataset.csv
```

Comment: Why do you have multiple `{FS=","}` blocks? Shouldn't that be done once in the `BEGIN` block?

Comment: I need to do it in 2 different commands

Comment: I don't understand, I thought both were in the same `test.awk` file.

Comment: Maybe you just need to remove `1` from the end of the first line, so it only prints the line after all transformations are done.

Comment: please update the question with a sample set of input data as well as the expected output; make sure the input includes sample lines that demonstrate both `gsub()` calls as well as some lines the `gsub()` calls will not modify

Comment: The right approach to solving a problem is almost never to take a bunch of separate scripts that solve small problems and stuff them all into a single file, but instead to come up with a sensible solution to the bigger problem. In this case, for example, your code is setting FS twice, both in  the wrong place, calling 2 separate `gsub()`s when 1 would do it, testing static true conditions twice, and printing the resulting records twice. There's a simple solution for what I think you might be trying to do but this isn't a good starting point. Provide a [mcve] to get help.

Answer (score 2):

Put both commands in the same block.

```
BEGIN {FS=","}
{   gsub(/\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}/,"");
    gsub(/:[0-9][0-9]/,"");
}1
```

You could also do them in the same regexp with alternation, since the replacement is the same.

And since you never do anything that operates on individual fields, there's no need to set the field separator.

```
{gsub(/:[0-9][0-9]|\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}/, "")}1
```

Comment: make it ::::: gawk 'gsub(/:[0-9][0-9]|\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}/, \_)^\_' :::: no need use 2 action blocks when one suffices …………….better yet, make that into FS, set OFS to blank, then just NF=NF as main code

Comment: I showed how to use one action block in the second part of my answer.

Comment: the 2nd half is 2 blocks - 1st one is the one with gsub(), 2nd one is the implicit print that follows the '} 1' - run ur code using 'gawk -p-' and you'll know what i mean. it's about what awk sees, not what we as humans see.

Comment: because in the end of the day, my opinion doesn't matter, your opinion doesn't matter, nor anyone else's - the only thing that matters is what awk sees.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're suggesting, maybe you should post your own answer so you can format it readably. Also, I don't want to use gawk-specific features if it can be done with standard awk.

Answer (score 0):

@***bramaawk*** : what this -

```
echo 'abc:12/31/2046def' |

awk '{gsub(/:[0-9][0-9]|\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}/, "")}1'
```

.. looks like to any `awk` is -

```
abcdef
    # gawk profile, created Sun Jun  5 10:59:06 2022

    # Rule(s)

     1  {
     1      gsub(/:[0-9][0-9]|\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}/,"",$0)
    }

     1  1 { # 1
     1      print
    }
```

what I'm suggesting is to streamline those into 1 single block :

```
awk 'gsub(":[0-9]{2}|[/][0-9]{1,2}[/][0-9]{4}",_)^_'
```

so that `awk` only needs to see :

```
# gawk profile, created Sun Jun  5 10:59:34 2022

# Rule(s)

 1  gsub(":[0-9]{2}|[/][0-9]{1,2}[/][0-9]{4}",_,$0)^_ { # 1
 1      print
}
```

instead of 2 `boolean evaluations` (or the poorly-termed "`patterns`"), and 2 `action blocks`, make them 1 each instead.

To make your solution generic for `gawk+mawk+nawk`, just do

```
{m,n,g}awk NF++ FS=':[0-9][0-9]|[/][0-9][0-9]?[/][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' OFS=
```